# django regroup templatetag does not group properly

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have following template

```
{% regroup product.hotel.facilities.all by facilitytype as facilities %}
{% for facility in facilities %}
       <h5>{{ facility.grouper }}</h5>

       <p class="tab-content-title bld">
          {% for i in facility.list %}
           <li>{{ i }}</li>
           {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
```

And following model structure:

```
class Hotel(TranslatableModel):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    facilities = models.ManyToManyField('hotels.Facility',null=True)

class Facility(TranslatableModel):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    facilitytype = models.ForeignKey(FacilityType, null=True, blank=True)

    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True),
    )
```

But when I run the page i see below. Instead I want to see the list grouped and distinct by facility_types: 
Any ideas? 
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm assuming you wanted the bolded header to appear above the bullet points?

Comment: No I want facilitytype to be distinct. Grouped and showed just once

Comment: when I do values. I get `{'code': u'55', 'id': 254, 'facilitytype_id': 11}
{'code': u'54', 'id': 253, 'facilitytype_id': 11}
{'code': u'53', 'id': 252, 'facilitytype_id': 12}
{'code': u'52', 'id': 251, 'facilitytype_id': 10}
{'code': u'51', 'id': 250, 'facilitytype_id': 10}
{'code': u'50', 'id': 249, 'facilitytype_id': 11}
{'code': u'49', 'id': 248, 'facilitytype_id': 10}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to sort your data by the grouper field first.